# set custom filename with JSZIP

Tags: javascript, jszip

I've coded out a zip-download, but the problem that i'm facing is that i can't manage to give the .zip a custom filename It keeps giving me some random name like these "ff22f3dc-24dc-41cb-b83d-06acef1694d0.zip". Is there an option or something similar to set it?

The way I init my download is by using this piece of code. I'm not working with an 'a' tag btw.

```
jszip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
                .then(function(content)
                {
                    window.location = URL.createObjectURL(content);
                });
        }
```

I'm thankful for every advice.

EDIT: this zip contains Excel files (working with JSZIP Utils)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page in the documentation](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/write_zip.html), it's possible to use the [FileSaver polyfill](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to give your download a custom filename. It only works on modern browsers though, you will need to use feature detection to fall back to the default behaviour.

See if this works:

```
try {
    var isFileSaverSupported = !!new Blob;
} catch (e) {}

jszip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" })
    .then(function(content) {
        if(isFileSaverSupported) {
            saveAs(content, "custom_filename.zip");
        } else {
            window.location = URL.createObjectURL(content);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm pretty confident that this would work, but is there a way without using another library?